# '<' character in property value strips rest of string

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When adding a node in Neo4j with Cypher by:

`CREATE (a: testNode {text: 'te>st<ignored' })
RETURN a.text`

This returns: "te>st".

How come the rest of the string is stripped due to the character '<'?

Comment: Which version of the Neo4j Browser (and which web browser) are you using? I can't replicate it on my version, so something is different here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j is not ignoring the rest of the string, It'd storing as it is and also returning the same. But there is some issue with the Neo4j browser, It's not showing it properly.

You can verify this by viewing results in text format in the Neo4j browser.

Please find screenshot below:
[image]

**Neo4j browser considers it as a start of HTML tag and hence doesn't show it properly. You can try adding HTML tags in the text and it will render the same in the output.**

Here is an example:

If you add an input tag it shows the input box.

```
CREATE (a: testNode {text: 'test input <input type="text" name="fname">' })
RETURN a.text
```

[image]